# Samsung Galaxy S5 Password

Tags: password, locked-out, android-device-manager

I inadvertently set a password for my Samsung Galaxy S5 that I cannot remember. I tried resetting it via google device manager (lock) option and I get the following message:

"Since google has verified that a screen lock is already set, the password that you entered won’t be needed"

Any ideas no how to log back into my phone without factory reset?

thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: I've just added the `locked-out` tag to your question. Please check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info), which gives some background, first-aid, and useful links which should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same problem, and was locked out for full day. I used findmymobile.samsung.com to unlock. I dont think you need to be enrolled to use the faciltiy. Thank God my problem is resolved. Give it a try, ADM was clearly not working